# Disable vscode comments - Flutter

Tags: flutter

How to disable this type of comment? As the picture shows.
[image vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTc8A.png)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can disable them by adding

> `"dart.closingLabels": false`

in your vscode settings file. Once you save the settings file it will ask you to Reload the Project.

Comment: How to disable it in Android Studio?

Comment: In Android Studio you can disable it by going into - Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Appearance and uncheck "Show closing labels in Dart source code"

Comment: Thank you, that was so annoying, This should be marked as answered.