# How to disable "fake" closing-bracket comments in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, dart

I'm not sure what the name of this feature is, but it is driving me nuts. I have only written a little bit of Dart in Visual Studio Code, so I don't know if this happens in other language modes.

Given the following code:

```
class FriendlychatApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: "Friendlychat",
      home: new ChatScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

VSCode will show:

```
class FriendlychatApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: "Friendlychat",
      home: new ChatScreen(),
    ); // MaterialApp
  }
}
```

This happens if the closing bracket is a paren (`)`) or square bracket (`]`).

Note that `// MaterialApp` is not actually written to the file, it is only rendered on screen.

This gets noisy rather quickly, and is quite redundant as VSCode displays indent lines already.

Is there a setting to disable this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can disable them by adding

> `"dart.closingLabels": false`

in your vscode settings file. Once you save the settings file it will ask you to Reload the Project.

Source: [Disable vscode comments - Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49312440/disable-vscode-comments-flutter)